# Does spheres of dimension n≥2 admit ­symmetric flat connections?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I need reference where they talk about to prove that spheres of dimension n≥2 don't admit ­­­­symmetric flat connections.

Comment: The proof that a compact manifold of finite fundamental group has no symmetric flat affine connection is that the developing map is defined on the universal covering space, a local diffeomorphism to affine space, equivariant under the fundamental group. The universal covering space is clearly compact too, so the map can't be a local diffeomorphism, since affine space is not compact. This works for all (X,G)-structures with noncompact X.

Comment: I will thank you for your clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manifolds which admit symmetric flat connections are known as affine manifolds. A standard result on these spaces is that the fundamental group of a compact affine manifold must be infinite.

For a reference,  see Corollary 1.14 of the following lectures.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03624

Comment: I will thank you for your clarification